# Using asynchronous thread and return to variable in the original called function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I understand how to use functions and also asynchronous functions with binding applying and calling. But I'm searching for a solution for the following for a long time.

To clarify why this is not a duplicate: I know how asynchronous calls work. I also understand why a variable isn't updated directly (due to the time difference between the start and the end of the call). My question simplified: is it possible to return to the original function and populate the variable?

Consider the following JavaScript pseudo code:

```
var returnedData = loadDataThroughAjax(url);

function loadDataThroughAjax(url)
{
    //here fires an xhrrequest using the specific url

    return xhr.readystatefunction = function()
    {
        if (this.reaystate == 4)
        {
            return this.responseText;
        }
    }


}
```

I would like the `responsetext` of the call to be loaded in the var `returnedData` in a single thread. I looked at some `jquery` code and there it looked like you could pull this of, or is the thing I'm asking impossible for an asynchronous call?

Comment: You can't do that.  Use promises.

Comment: @SLaks Promises is experimental and not supported by IE.

Comment: @Mouser then use a library that implements promises (like jquery) or write your own implementation. Either way, a promise is the way to go here.

Comment: @prodigitalson Promises indeed look promising (pun intended). Also IE is going to support them soon. However I do not want to use libraries. JQuery promise implementation is flawed I read. Do you or somebody else have any lead on how to write a polyfill or know a good polyfill not library depended?

Comment: While I know JQ promises are different they have worked form me just fine and since I almost always use JQ I have never had a reason to use something else with a proper implementation. There is this polyfill from [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org): https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-6.0.0.min.js